# Get user's friends that are using the app, too

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

i want to get a user's friends who are using the app too. I currently achieve this by getting all the friends

```
FB.api('/me/friends?fields=id,name,updated_time&date_format=U&<?=$access_token?>',
    { limit: 500 },
        function(response) {
            alert(response.data.length + ' friends');
});
```

and then checking if I can see them in my database, using an ajax call.

The thing that this isn't really what I need, because:

- This way I will consider users that are no longer using the app
- It makes difficult to present the friends as I first have them all in an array and then, with delay, this array is updated and so on.

So the question is, can I get this information from the Graph API directly? (something like `is_app_user` = 1 or 0)

Comment: You can do it with FQL – the `user` table has a field `is_app_user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either add the installed field when asking for friends, like so:

```
/USER_ID/friends?fields=installed
```

and only the friends who installed your app will have this field set.

You can also use FQL intead:

```
SELECT uid
FROM user  
WHERE is_app_user=1 AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())
```

I prefer the FQL version, since it returns the short list from the start.

Comment: First solution suited my needs. Thanks!